# getting the direct content of an html element encapsulated in a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have an piece of html in a jquery object.  When I say $(this).html() I get:

```
<span class="value">4</span><span class="type">teaspoons</span>butter
```

I want to get only the piece of text from this html segment that is not in the spans. in this example, it is butter.

How do I get that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476787/jquery-innertext-not-including-sub-element

Comment: Also essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775893/how-to-get-the-text-of-a-div-which-is-not-a-part-of-any-other-container-in-jquery/3003950#3003950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the easy but cheating way, drop all the children and get the text property

```
var tmp = $(".post-text").clone();
tmp.children().remove();
tmp.text();
```

**EDIT** There is also a [Text Children plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/textchildren/) that does this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textvalues = $(this).contents().map(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 ? this.nodeValue : null;
});
```

Comment: Not really, you can use `.contents()` :)

Answer (score 0):

This example uses [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) to get all the children nodes (including text nodes), then uses [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to turn each child node into a string based on the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).  If the node is a text node (i.e. text not within the spans), we return its [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue).

This returns a jQuery set containing strings, so we call [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get a 'standard' array object that we can call [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on.

```
// our 'div' that contains your code:
var $html = $('<div><span class="value">4</span><span class="type">teaspoons</span>butter</div>');

// Map the contents() into strings
$html.contents().map(function() { 
  // if the node is a textNode, use its nodeValue, otherwise empty string
  return this.nodeType == 3 ? this.nodeValue : ''; 
  // get the array, and join it together:
}).get().join('');

// "butter"
```

If you need to do this a lot, you could make a quick plugin:

```
$.fn.directText = function() {
   return this.contents().map(function() {
     return this.nodeType == 3 ? this.nodeValue : '';
   }).get().join('');
};
```

Or a slightly more robust version that supports stripping whitespace / changing the text that it joins the resulting array with:

```
$.fn.directText = function(settings) {
   settings = $.extend({},$.fn.directText.defaults, settings);
   return this.contents().map(function() {
     if (this.nodeType != 3) return undefined; // remove non-text nodes
     var value = this.nodeValue;
     if (settings.trim) value = $.trim(value);
     if (!value.length) return undefined; // remove zero-length text nodes
     return value;
   }).get().join(settings.joinText);
};

$.fn.directText.defaults = {
   trim: true,
   joinText: ''
};
```