# How to get the text of a div which is not a part of any other container in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This should be real easy. Given below is the HTML.

```
<div id='attachmentContainer'>
    #Attachment#
    <span id='spnAttachmentName' class='hidden'>#AttachmentName#</span>
    <span id='spnAttachmentPath' class='hidden'>#AttachmentPath#</span>
</div>
```

I want to get just the #Attachment# and not the other text. When I tried

```
$("#attachmentContainer").text()
```

it gives out all #Attachment#, #AttachmentName# as well as #AttachmentPath#. I know I could just put #Attachment# into another span and access it directly but I was just intrigued on how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476787/jquery-innertext-not-including-sub-element

Comment: This might be one of those rare times where breaking out into pure javascript may not be a bad idea ...

Comment: @James: jQuery is "pure JavaScript" from top to bottom. I'm not sure why people always think that "JavaScript" and "HTML DOM handling" are the same thing. JavaScript *is the language*, and the DOM is merely one API that is available to it.

Comment: Yep. It is javascript. But is it pure? No. Its a functional layer to abstract and unify DOM manipulation.

Comment: @James: To be pedantic, jQuery is pure JavaScript as well, by all definitions of the word "pure". But I understand what you mean. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your text happens to be the first child node of the `<div>`:

```
var firstChild = $("#attachmentContainer")[0].firstChild;
var textValue  = firstChild.nodeType == 3 ? $.trim(firstChild.nodeValue) : "";
```

The `nodeType` check is meant to be a safeguard - it makes sure you are actually handling a text node - the `firstChild` might be something different after all. React accordingly, this is just an example.

To retrieve the value of all text children (or a specific one), just loop over the `childNodes` collection of your element, concatenating all bits you find into a string:

```
// the optional "at" parameter lets you define which text node you want
// if not given, this returns all text nodes concatenated
$.fn.ownText = function(at) { 
  var result = [], node = this[0];
  if (!(node && node.childNodes)) return;
  for (var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = node.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType != 3) continue;
    var t = $.trim(child.nodeValue);
    if (t != '') result.push(t);
  }
  return at ? result[at-1] : result.join(' ');
}

var text = $("#attachmentContainer").ownText();  // all text children
var text = $("#attachmentContainer").ownText(1); // first text child only
```

Comment: what if its not the first child? what if you don't know the index?

Comment: @hunter - see changed answer.

Comment: @hunter: Good point...but in my case I have it as a template. so it will always be the first child.

Answer (score 6):

This will get you just that items text

```
var $item = $("#attachmentContainer").clone();
$item.children().remove(); 
alert($item.text());
```

clone the object so you don't have to remove the actual items children. Then you can remove the child elements and that will leave the innerText of the item you want.

And here's a handy little method to do this easily

```
jQuery.fn.trueText = function(obj){
    var $item = $(obj).clone();
    $item.children().remove(); 
    return $item.text();
};
```

Now you can call `$("#attachmentContainer").trueText()`

Comment: I think this is more readable and more jQuery-able than Tomalaks answer, but to each its own

Comment: @Hunter This might involve less code, but it certainly involves a *lot* more DOM manipulation, which is one of the slower parts of JavaScript.

Comment: @hunter: I guess `clone()` can be expensive under certain circumstances. And it would work if there aren't any other text nodes that you are *not* interested in - it can not get the first text child.

Comment: @hunter - An even more jQuery way that doesn't involve cloning/altering nodes has been posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775893/how-to-get-the-text-of-a-div-which-is-not-a-part-of-any-other-container-in-jquery/3003950#3003950

Answer (score 2):

$('#attachmentContainer').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType==3;}).text()

Comment: I believe you should explicitly check that `nodeType===3` (text node) rather than nodeType!=1.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeType) for the other potential nodeType values your `filter` function will return.  Otherwise, very elegant solution.

Comment: @meagar: thanks, you're totally right. Had to look more thoroughly for node types.

Comment: Nice straightforward solution, +1. It will return excess whitespace, though. *(Please also edit in the correction from @meagar's comment.)*

Answer (score 1):

> Copied from [my own answer on a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626750/getting-the-direct-content-of-an-html-element-encapsulated-in-a-jquery-object/3003839#3003839)

This example uses [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) to get all the children nodes (including text nodes), then uses [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to turn each child node into a string based on the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).  If the node is a text node (i.e. text not within the spans), we return its [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue).

This returns a jQuery set containing strings, so we call [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get a 'standard' array object that we can call [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on.

```
// our 'div' that contains your code:
var $html = $("<div id='attachmentContainer'>\n    #Attachment#\n    <span id='spnAttachmentName' class='hidden'>#AttachmentName#</span>\n    <span id='spnAttachmentPath' class='hidden'>#AttachmentPath#</span>\n</div>");

// Map the contents() into strings
$html.contents().map(function() { 
  // if the node is a textNode, use its nodeValue, otherwise empty string
  return this.nodeType == 3 ? this.nodeValue : ''; 
  // get the array, and join it together:
}).get().join('');

// " 
//     #Attachment# 
//     
//     
// "
```

If you want to trim extra whitespace, you can use `$.trim(this.nodeValue)`

If you need to do this a lot, you could even make a plugin (now with some options):

```
$.fn.directText = function(settings) {
   settings = $.extend({},$.fn.directText.defaults, settings);
   return this.contents().map(function() {
     if (this.nodeType != 3) return undefined; // remove non-text nodes
     var value = this.nodeValue;
     if (settings.trim) value = $.trim(value);
     if (!value.length) return undefined; // remove zero-length text nodes
     return value;
   }).get().join(settings.joinText);
};

$.fn.directText.defaults = {
   trim: true,
   joinText: ''
};
```

Comment: great idea to use map and then join. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the text is actually a text element - a child of the parent div. So you just need to query for the first child. Not sure though. hth

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper well-formed angle would be to put that first part in a `<p> </p>` (if a span was not appropriate).

I thought I could get a .filter to work on it, but couldn't quite get it...