# Simple Tag Extraction in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have

```
<p id="target">
  <span><sup>$</sup>50</span>
</p>

var $p = $("p#target");
```

How do I get just the text *50* from `$p` i.e. without the dollar sign?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery InnerText not including sub element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476787/jquery-innertext-not-including-sub-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var clone = $("#target").clone();
clone.find("sup").remove();
var text = clone.text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ANp9y/

...or, if it's only ever a dollar you need to worry about:

```
var text = $.trim($("#target").text().replace("$", ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var num = $("#target > span")[0].lastChild.data;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FJmLd/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
var a = $('#target span').text();
var b = a.split('$');
alert(b[1]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2mgeC/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the contents and concatenate the trimmed text nodes:

```
var text = $("#target span").contents().map(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE){
        return $.trim(this.nodeValue);
    }
}).toArray().join();
alert(text); //50
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j527G/)